# Grouping Dataframe by Date, Adding Count of Character

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, grouping, magrittr

Pretty embarrassed to post this because it's super basic but I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. I have a dataframe with dates and gender.

```
# A tibble: 119,186 x 2
   date       gender
   <date>     <fct> 
 1 2020-01-02 male  
 2 2020-01-02 male  
 3 2020-01-02 male  
 4 2020-01-02 female
 5 2020-01-02 male  
 6 2020-01-02 female
 7 2019-12-25 male  
 8 2019-12-25 male  
 9 2019-12-25 female
10 2019-12-25 female
# … with 119,176 more rows
```

I'm trying to create a dataframe that is sorted by date and gender with the count of each - here's a hypothetical

```
   date       gender   count 
 1 2020-01-02 male     4
 2 2020-01-02 female   2
 3 2019-12-25 male     2
 4 2019-12-25 female.  2
 ... etc
```

I have tried a bunch of things to get this to work, like counting:

```
> df_gender %>% 
+   group_by(date) %>%
+   summarize(count = count(gender))
  count.x count.freq
1    male      69217
2  female      49969
```

And adding a column:

```
date       gender cases
   <date>     <fct>  <dbl>
 1 2020-01-02 male       1
 2 2020-01-02 male       1
 3 2020-01-02 male       1
 4 2020-01-02 female     1
 5 2020-01-02 male       1
 6 2020-01-02 female     1
 7 2019-12-25 male       1
 8 2019-12-25 male       1
 9 2019-12-25 female     1
10 2019-12-25 female     1
# … with 119,176 more rows

> df_gender %>% 
+   group_by(date) %>%
+   summarize(count = sum(cases))
   count
1 119186
```

I feel like this should work (and has worked in other contexts) - so I've been troubleshooting my date variable. I think it's properly formatted:

```
glimpse(df_gender$date)
 Date[1:119186], format: "2020-01-02" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-02" ...
```

Vaguely losing my mind here. Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for wasting time with this!

Comment: Just do `count(df_gender, date,  gender)`?

Comment: No sadly not. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Running that gives me:  > count(df_gender, date, gender)
Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: The dplyr solution from the link above gives this:

Comment: > df_gender %>%
+   group_by(date, gender) %>%
+   mutate(count = n())
Error: n() should only be called in a data context
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>

Comment: There are conflicts somewhere. Try restarting R, load only `dplyr` without any other package, especially not `plyr`, and redo. The function should work fine.

Comment: Ugh that absolutely fixed it. plyr was clearly the problem.  THANK YOU for spending your time on such a worthless issue.  Really appreciate it.